# Performance Difference between Apache Ignite compute grid and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I need to do some computation on a large set of data. In this computation, data will be manipulated and stored (persisted) to Database. 

So can anyone suggest which technology is preferable in accordance with performance and Resource Utilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way here is to implement your logic and check how it works with both frameworks. Also, you can run different benchmarks in your environment.

Information about benchmarks for Apache Ignite you and read here:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/perfomance-benchmarking

In case of any technical questions, you can ask them to the community.